# Why downloading tiff doesn't work in Firefox?

Tags: angularjs

In my project i use AngularJS so a directive for downloading files was created. It contains the following:

```
   scope.$on('downloaded', function(event, data) {
                var hiddenLink = document.createElement('a');

                $(hiddenLink).attr({
                    href: 'data:application/tiff;base64,' + data.Attachment,
                    download: data.AttachmentFileName
                });

                if (isIEorFirefox) {
                    $(hiddenLink).click(function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();

                        var byteString = atob(data.Attachment);
                        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
                        var intArray = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                            intArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
                        }

                        var blob = new Blob([buffer],{type:'image/tiff'});
                        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, data.AttachmentFileName);
                    });
                    $(hiddenLink).trigger('click');
                } else {
                    hiddenLink.click();
                }
            });
```

Previously there was an issue - download in IE simply didn't start - but for now as you can it has been eliminated. Though another issue remains - currently this code doesn't start download in Firefox. There is only one question - why?

**UPDATE:**

I've updated initial code because it didn't save file properly in IE. Now it does. Searching over the web i still cannot find a way to make file download in FF. Moreover FF still seems not to have any native way to save files according to this article https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/why-no-filesystem-api-in-firefox/. I would be grateful if someone prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
 hiddenLink.click();
```

should perhaps be:

```
$(hiddenLink).click();
```

or same as other:

```
$(hiddenLink).trigger('click');
```

Assume you also need the event handler added as well...

Comment: Well this one - hiddenLink.click(); - makes use of native JS click event and works fine in Chrome, IE and Opera.

Comment: Might be a version issue, firefox 5 or later OK, prior not. "Prior to Gecko 5.0, Gecko didn't implement the click method on other elements that might be expected to respond to mouse–clicks such as links (<a> elements), nor would it necessarily fire the click event of other elements." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click